# Is it bad design for a class to give access to its data (via ptr/it) when this data can be deleted before the class object is out of scope?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, iterator

Classic example is iterator invalidation :

```
std::string test("A");
auto it = test.insert(test.begin()+1,'B');
test.erase();
...
std::cout << *it;
```

Do you think having this kind of API is bad design, and will be difficult to learn/use for beginners ?

A costly, performance/memory wise, solution would be, in that type of case, to assign the pointer/iterator to an empty string (or a nullptr, but that's not very helpful) when a clear method is used.

**Some precisions**

I'm thinking of this design for returning const chars* that can be modified internally (maybe they're stored in a std::vector that can be cleared). I don't want to return a std::string (binary compatibility) and I don't want a get(char*,std::size_t) method because of the size argument that needs to be fetched (too slow). Also I don't want to create a wrapper around std::string or my own string class.

Comment: So the question is, "Are the C++ standard library classes badly designed?", right? C++ is a fairly low-level language with different concerns from most OOP languages. The result is different design and different idioms...

Comment: It's not no so much "Are the C++ standard library classes badly designed?" as can we adopt a similar design without feeling too guilty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend reading up on [Stepanov's design philosophy](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf) (pages 9-11):

> [This example] is written in a clear object-oriented style with getters and setters. The proponents of this style say that the advantage of having such functions is that it allows programmers later on to change the implementation. What they forget to mention is that sometimes it is awfully good to expose the implementation. Let us see what I mean. It is hard for me to imagine an evolution of a system that would let you keep the interface of get and set, but be able to change the implementation. I could imagine that the implementation outgrows `int` and you need to switch to `long`. But that is a different interface. I can imagine that you decide to switch from an array to a list but that also will force you to change the interface, since it is really not a very good idea to index into a linked list.
>
> Now let us see why it is really good to expose the implementation. Let us assume that tomorrow you decide to sort your integers. How can you do it? Could you use the `C` library `qsort`? No, since it knows nothing about your getters and setters. Could you use the STL `sort`? The answer is the same. While you design your class to survive some hypothetical change in the implementation, you did not design it for the very common task of sorting. Of course, the proponents of getters and setters will suggest that you extend your interface with a member function `sort`. After you do that, you will discover that you need binary search and median, etc. Very soon your class will have 30 member functions but, of course, it will be hiding the implementation. And that could be done only if you are the owner of the class. Otherwise, you need to implement a decent sorting algorithm on top of the setter-getter interface from scratch and that is a far more difficult and dangerous activity than one can imagine. ...
>
> Setters and getters make our daily programming hard but promise huge rewards in the future when we discover better ways to store arrays of integers in memory. But I do not know a single realistic scenario when hiding memory locations inside our data structure helps and exposure hurts; it is, therefore, my obligation to expose a much more convenient interface that also happens to be consistent with the familiar interface to the `C` arrays. When we program in `C++` we should not be ashamed of its `C` heritage, but make full use of it. The only problems with `C++`, and even the only problems with `C`, arise when they themselves are not consistent with their own logic. ...
>
> My remark about exposing the address locations of consecutive integers is not facetious.
>   It took a major effort to convince the standard committee that such a requirement is an
>   essential property of vectors; they would not, however, agree that vector iterators should
>   be pointers and, therefore, on several major platforms – including the Microsoft one – it
>   is faster to sort your vector by saying the unbelievably ugly
>
> ```
> if (!v.empty()) {
>     sort(&*v.begin(), &*v.begin() + v.size());
> }
> ```
>
> than the intended
>
> ```
> sort(v.begin(), v.end());
> ```
>
> Attempts to impose pseudo-abstractness at the cost of efficiency can be defeated, but at a terrible cost.

[Stepanov has a lot of other interesting documents available](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/), especially in the "Class Notes" section.

Yes, there are several rules of thumb regarding OOP.  No, I'm not convinced that they are really the best way to do things.  When you're working with the STL it makes a lot of sense to do things the STL compatible way.  And when your abstraction is low level (like `std::vector`, which is meant specifically to make working with dynamically allocated arrays easier; i.e., it should be usable almost like an array with some added features), then some of those OOP rules of thumb make no sense at all.

To answer the original question:  even beginners will eventually need to learn about iterators, object lifetimes, and what I'll call an object's useful life (i.e., "the object hasn't fallen out of scope, but is no longer valid to use, like an invalidated iterator").  I don't see any reason to try to hide those facts of life from the user, so I personally wouldn't rule out an iterator-based API on those grounds.  The real question is what your API is meant to abstract and what's it's meant to expose (similar to the fact that a `vector` is a nicer array and is meant to expose its array nature).  If you answer that, you should have a better idea about whether an iterator-based API makes sense.

Comment: For the record, I prefer the PDFs in the "Class Notes" section of that website to the book _Elements of Programming_ that Stepanov wrote with McJones.

Comment: Without having read [This example], one possible switch for this kind of thing is from a vector-style contiguous array to a deque-style hidden collection of arrays. In which case you *would* change the getter implementation - I'm not sure whether Stepanov is being a bit sneaky by ignoring this possibility and instead using linked list as a straw man. Anyway, Stepanov did a good enough job with iterators that you can make that change, and as long as clients haven't assumed that iterators are pointers their iterator-based code will still work unchanged.

Comment: ...It's unfortunate if MS delivered a version of `vector` where the iterators can't be made as fast as pointers at high optimization levels, but I'd consider that a QOI issue rather than a problem with the interface, and I'm pretty sure it's no longer the case. +1 though, since although I'd quibble some of the details of Stepanov's argument, the general point is that the STL design meets its criteria and sets idioms for a particular style of programming. When OOP-only people do things completely differently it's usually because they started with different goals.

Comment: You are right that the jump between `vector` and `deque` is mush smaller than the jump between `vector` and `list`.  I have to assume that Stepanov was trying to make a point and did so using the two most diametrically opposed containers.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott Meyers states in Effective C++: yes it is indeed not a good design to grant access to private/protected members via pointers, iterators or references because you never know what the client code will do with it.

As far as I can remember this should be avoided, and it is sometimes better to create a copy of data members which are then returned to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad or faulty implementation rather than design.
As for providing access to private or protected members through pointers, basically it destroys one of the basic OOP principle of `Abstraction`.

I am unsure though as to what the question is, Yes ofcourse it is bad to have implementation which invalidates iterator. What is the real Q here?

Comment: Don't you mean 'principle of Encapsulation'?